# Needing suggestions/guidance to create a newenvironment for a table that will be used multiple times

Tags: macros, errors, environments, tabularx, texstudio

I'm a beginner with LaTeX or TeX in general.

I use Tex Studio to write any LaTeX document.

I'm writing a document that requires many tables, all based on the same template, think about copy&paste with different content.

Looking on the Internet for a way to reuse the table code, it seems that commands and environments are what I need.
I know, more or less, how to make the table from scratch using booktabs and tabularx, even if I still haven't studied how LaTeX really works. We can say that I'm still at the script kiddie state, even if I try to find why some code works in a way and why it doesn't in another.

---

My environment:

```
Windows 10 x64 2004

TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22)
Using Qt Version 5.12.1, compiled with Qt 5.12.1 R

PDFLATEX: pdflatex.exe -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.0.1 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
```

---

This is what I did:

```
\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]%
{%
\stepcounter{usecase}%
\tabularx{\linewidth}{lX} \toprule%
\textbf{\#\arabic{usecase}} & \textbf{#1}\\ \midrule
}
{\bottomrule%
\endtabularx}%

\newcommand{\desc}[1]{\textbf{Description} & {#1}\\ \midrule}
\newcommand{\precond}[1]{\textbf{Preconditions} & {#1}\\}
\newcommand{\postcond}[1]{\textbf{Postconditions} & {#1}\\ \midrule}
\newcommand{\basicpath}[1]{\textbf{Basic Path} & {#1}\\}
\newcommand{\altpath}[1]{\textbf{Alternate Path} & {#1}\\}
\newcommand{\expath}[1]{\textbf{Exception Path} & {#1}\\}
```

But it raises multiple errors, even if they are the same:

### `Misplaced \noalign. \end{usecase}`

This is what I want to achieve:

```
\begin{usecase}{Title}
\desc{Very long desc with \textbf{formatting} but no environments}
\precond{Pre condition text with
    \begin{itemize}
    \item One item
    \item Two item
    \end{itemize}
} % precond
\postcond{test}  % like precond, just skipping
\basicpath{test} % like precond, just skipping
\altpath{test}   % like precond, just skipping
\expath{test}    % like precond, just skipping
\end{usecase}
```

The actual table will be like that:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX} \toprule
\textbf{\#1} & \textbf{Title of The Use Case}\\ \midrule
\textbf{Description} &%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam, metus a finibus efficitur, tortor enim consequat arcu, nec congue.
\\% description text
\midrule
\textbf{Preconditions} & Precondition text\\
\textbf{Postconditions} & Postconditions text\\ \midrule
\textbf{Basic Path} & User does this and this:
                      \begin{itemize}
                      \item Step 1
                      \item Step 2
                      \item Step 3
                      \item Step 4
                      \item Step 5
                      \end{itemize}\\
\textbf{Alternate Path} & Alternate Path (optional)\\
\textbf{Exception Path} & Exception Path (optional)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

P.S.

The table doesn't render perfectly because it's the preview. It's perfect if I open it on Adobe Reader.

Comment: In your `usecase` environment, the closing `}` of `\desc` is missing. Also, your definition of `\expath` is missing its `\\ `.

Comment: Since you used `h!`: Do you actually want your tables to float or do you want them to be inserted exactly where they are placed in the code?

Comment: You should also move `\addtocounter{usecase}{1}` or `\stepcounter{usecase}` into the definition of the `usecase` environment. Otherwise the counter will stey at the value 1 throughout the document.

Comment: @leandriis I want the table to be placed right there, because otherwise it's placed in a different section/page etc.
Will updated the code thanks!

Comment: If you don't want the table to float, drop the `table` environment entirely. Also, `\centering` is not really neccessary since the table is as wide ast the textwidth already.

Comment: @leandriis how do I center it then? Simply between a center environment?

Comment: If y table is as wide as the textwidth, there is just no point in centering it anyways. Left alignment, centered alignment and right alignment will give the exact same output if your table reaches from one margin all the way to the other margin.

Comment: @leandriis I updated the code as suggested, yet the error stays :(

Comment: The cause for the error must be hidden somewhere else then. If I use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
`, then the most recent version of `usecases` environment definition followed by `\begin{document} \begin{usecase}{Title}..... \end{document}`, the document compiles perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @leandriis I found the culprit and to be honest I don't know what to say!
`\usepackage[datesep=/]{datetime2}` I'm using this package to print \today as `YYYY/MM/DD` but to be honest I found later that I don't need it....
Everything works now

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue even with `datetime2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit was "hidden" and, honestly, unimaginable for me:

> `\usepackage{datetime2}`

Without this package, the document compiles without problems.

Interestingly, it doesn't create problem if you use a `tabularx` environment like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{<cols>}
\end{tabularx}
```

But it does if you use it inside a `\newenvironment` with tabularx macros:

```
\newenvironment{env}
{\tabularx{<width>}{<cols>}}
{\endtabularx}

\begin{env}
\end{env} % Error: Misplaced \noalign.
```